# Android generating wrong language code for Indonesia?

Tags: android, internationalization

This is happening on all of the devices we have in Indonesia.

The country codes are correct, also the display language and ISO3 seem correct:

```
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country()     // "IDN"
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry()  // "Indonesia"
Locale.getDefault().getCountry()         // "ID"
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()    // "ind"
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() // "Bahasa Indonesia"
```

**But the normal language code is wrong, should be "id" instead of "in". And then android is also generating the wrong language_COUNTRY identifier, should be "id_ID" instead of "in_ID"**:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()        // "in"
Locale.getDefault().toString()           // "in_ID"
```

Is this a known problem? What can we do about it?

cyanide suggests just overwriting the locale, but what about the devices who really need to use "in" and not "id", it would be the wrong one for them then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, found out why it is happening, see the [Android Locale Constructor Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#Locale(java.lang.String)):

> > > ISO 639 is not a stable standard; some of the language codes it defines (specifically "iw", "ji", and "in") have changed. This constructor accepts both the old codes ("iw", "ji", and "in") and the new codes ("he", "yi", and "id"), but all other API on Locale will return only the OLD codes.

So not much we can do, use "in" inside the app for strings, etc. and convert it to "id" (or treat in as id) when talking to outside entities like backend servers.

Comment: It depends what the back-end servers use :-) If it is Java, they will also expect "in". Java still uses the legacy codes, and that is also the reason Android uses them: compatibility with the official JDK.

Comment: Backend is in node.js, but good point! Although I think I read the constructor accepts the new codes, only when asked for it returns the old ones for compatibility. Would say it's time for a support-locale lib. :p

Answer (score 2):

Check language settings on your device. If all right, then your system is dodgy, so you may try to upgrade it. As a matter of fact, configuration can be changed prorammatiically

```
   public void updateLocale(Resources rsrc) {
      Configuration conf = rsrc.getConfiguration();
      Locale locale = conf.locale;
      if (locale.getCountry().equals("ID") && locale.getLanguage().equals("in")) {
          conf.locale = new Locale("id", "ID");
          rsrc.updateConfiguration(conf, rsrc.getDisplayMetrics());
     }   
  }
```

However, it isn't really advisable;

Comment: hmm, it's not only my system, we have thousands of devices reporting with the wrong "in" language code and none with the correct "id" language code, so seems a problem in android itself. If you create a translated file in Android Studio it also uses the wrong "in" to create the resource folder "values-in" instead of "values-id".

Comment: not sure, but changing the locale could maybe break a few things like the translation feature in libs, so would not try that without a lot of testing. but nice to know you could do stuff like that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have a same experience and I found a reference in [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale#compatibility)

If you want to change old language code("iw", "ji", and "in") to new one("he", "yi", and "id"), you just use this API below

```kotlin
//kotlin
Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag()
```

Comment: The old and new language codes are reversed in this answer.